# How to approach feature elimination?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, modeling, feature-selection

I have been working on a couple of dataset to build predictive models based on them. However I am left a bit bewildered when its coming to elimination of features.

The first one is the *Boston Housing* dataset and the second is *Bigmart Sales* dataset. I will focus my question around these two however I would also appreciate relatively generalized answers too.

Boston Housing : I have constructed a correlation coefficient matrix and eliminated the features which has an absolute correlation coefficient of less than 0.50 with respect to the target variable *medv*. That is leaving me with three features. However, I also do understand that a correlation matrix can be highly deceptive and does not capture non-linear relationships and as a matter of fact features such as crim, indus etc does have non-linear relationship with medv and intuitively it simply does not feel correct to discard them right away.

Bigmart Sales : There are around 30+ features that is created after OneHotEncoding in Python. I have given a go to backward elimination method while I was constructing a linear regression model but I am not exactly sure how to apply backward elimination when I was working on a Decision Tree model for this dataset (not sure if it can actually be applied to Decision Tree at all).

It would be of great help if I can get some idea on how to approach to feature elimination for the above two cases. Let me know if you need more info, I will gladly provide.

Comment: Could you describe a single problem in-depth along with the context of that problem?  There are numerous approaches to feature selection and there is no single answer to your question.  How you perform feature selection could depend on the type of model you're using and what exactly your features are.

Comment: Hi @vealkind, I have edited my question and tried to make it more case specific. Let me know if it helped. Thanks a lot man for dropping by!

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely general question. I don't think that it possible to answer to your question in StackOverFlow format.

For every ML / Statistical model you need different Feature Elimination / Feature Engineering approach:

- Linear / Logistic / GLM models require removal of correlated features
- For Neural Nets / Boosted trees removal of features will heart performance of the model

Even for one type of models there's no single best way of doing Feature Elimination

If you can add more specific information to your question it'll be possible to discuss it in details.

Comment: Hi @Sergei I have edited my question. Thanks for trying to help at the first place!

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun one without any definitive answers ([No Free Lunch Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization)) that apply across the board. That said, there are many guidelines which typically have success in real-world problems. Those guidelines will work fine in the specific datasets you explicitly mentioned as well.

As with just about anything else, one must always consider the **purpose** of feature elimination. Without a goal or set of goals, any answer is valid. With an objective, not only can you hone in on a good answer, but it can open up the door to other ideas you may not have considered. Typically feature elimination is done for one of four reasons:

1. Increased Accuracy
2. Increased Generalization

   - Decreased Bias
   - Decreased Variance
3. Decreased Computational Costs
4. Ease of Explanation

Of course there are other reasons, but these cover the main use cases. With respect to any of those metrics, the obvious (and awful -- never do this) way to choose which ones to keep is to try all combinations in your model and see what happens. In the Boston Housing dataset, this yields 2^13=8192 possible combinations of features to test. The combinatorial growth is exponential, and not only is this approach likely to lead to survivorship bias, it is too expensive for most people and most data.

Barring any sort of a comprehensive examination of all possible options, one must use a **heuristic** of some kind to attempt to find the same results. I'll mention several:

- Train the model n times, each with precisely one feature removed (a different feature each time). If a model has poor performance it indicates that the removed feature is important.
- Train the model once with all features, and randomly perturb each input one feature at a time (this can be done stochastically if you don't want to waste time on every input). The features which cause the most classification error when perturbed are the ones which matter the most.
- As you said, perform some sort of correlation testing with the target variable to determine feature importance and a cross-correlation to remove duplicated linear information.

These different approaches have different assumptions and goals. Feature removal is important from a computational standpoint (many machine learning algorithms are quadratic or worse in the number of features), and with that perspective the goal is to preserve the behavior of the model as best as possible while removing as much information (i.e., as much complexity) as possible. In the Boston Housing data set, your cross-correlation analysis would probably leave you with Charles River Proximity, Nitrous Oxide Concentration, and Average Room Number as the most relevant variables. Between those three you capture nearly all the accuracy a linear model can obtain on the data.

One thing to point out is that feature removal by definition removes information. This can improve accuracy and generalization for only a few reasons.

- By removing **redundant** information, the model has less bias toward those features and is better able to generalize.
- By removing **noisy** information, the model can focus its efforts on features with high informational content. *Note* that this affects non-deterministic models like neural networks more than models like linear regressions. Linear regressions always converge to the one unique solution (except in special cases that happen with a true 0% probability where there are multiple solutions).

When you're throwing a lot of features into an algorithm (50k different genes for an organism for example), it makes a lot of sense that some of them won't carry any information. By definition then, any variance they have is noise that the model may inadvertently pick up instead of the signal we want. Feature removal is a common strategy in that domain which improves accuracy dramatically.

Contrast that with the Boston Housing data which has 13 carefully curated features, all of which carry information (based on eyeballing crude scatter plots with respect to the target variable). That particular reasoning isn't likely to affect accuracy much. Moreover, there aren't enough features for there to be very much bias introduced with duplicated information.

On top of that, there are hundreds of data points covering the majority of the input space, so even if we did have bias problems or extraneous features, there is more than enough data that the effects will be negligible. Perhaps enough to make or break the 1st or 2nd place winners in Kaggle, but not enough to make the difference between a good analysis and a great analysis.

Especially if you're using a linear algorithm on top though, having fewer features can greatly aid in the explainability of a model. If you restrict your model to those three variables, it's pretty easy to tell a person that you know houses in the area are expensive because they're all waterfront, they're huge, and they have nice lawns (nitrous oxide indicates fertilizer usage).

Removing features is only a small portion of feature engineering, and another important technique is the addition of features. Adding features usually amounts to low-order polynomial interactions (as an example, the `age` variable has a fairly weak correlation to the `medv` variable, but if you square it then the data straightens out a bit and improves the correlation).

Adding features (and removing them) can be aided greatly with a little domain knowledge. I don't know a ton about housing, so I can't add a lot of help here, but in other domains like credit worthiness you can easily imagine combining debt and income features to get a ratio of debt to income as a single feature. Reshaping those features so that they linearly correlate to your output and represent **physically meaningful** quantities in the domain is a big part of obtaining accuracy and generalizability.

With respect to generalizability and domain knowledge, even with something as simple as a linear model it's important to be able to explain why a feature is important. Just because the data says that nitrous oxide matters in the test set doesn't mean that it will carry any predictive weight in the train set as well. Especially as the number of features grows and the amount of data shrinks, you will expect such correlations to occur purely by accident. Having a physical interpretation (nitrous oxide corresponds to nice lawns) yields confidence that the model isn't learning spurious correlations.

Comment: Thanks Hans for a really insightful answer. You have described a number of things which I will be trying on now. One of the main aspect of your answer to me was you described how to think about the problem in hand, which is exactly what I was looking for. I shall be reverting back to you once I try the things you have described (might take me some time). As for the specific dataset of 'Boston Housing' the model I have created already has an 84% R-Square score, so I am kinda aware that there is little room for improvement, however I want to dig further solely out of academic interest mate.